# Append window.onload

Tags: onload

How do I append window.onload in javascript.  I want to be able to add a function to what might already be defined for window.onload.  So if I have

```
<body onload="function1();">
```

I want to have "function1(); function2();" defined for the page load.

is there something like window.onload += "function2();";

Thanks.

Comment: You could have function1() call function2() just before #1 returns, or you use jquery and have as many `$(document).ready(...)` calls as you want.

Comment: @Marc-b I do not know all the functions being called.  So I am looking for a way to append to window.onload.

Comment: Please read this: http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/onloads/index.html but keep in mind that if other coders call `window.onload = function1();` after you, this is of no use.

Answer (score 1):

You can call one method that calls another methods.

```
<body onload="function1();">


function function1(){
function2();
function3();
function4();
}
```

**edit:**
but I would rather code a jQuery driven solution, by using:

```
$(function(){
// here you implement whatever you need, even call other functions.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple "window.onload = function() { ... }" statements.

But if you want to use , maybe you can try something like this:

```
<body onload="func1(), func2(), func3()">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (window.addEventListener) // W3C standard
    {
      window.addEventListener('load', myFunction, false); // NB **not** 'onload'
    } 
    else if (window.attachEvent) // Microsoft
    {
      window.attachEvent('onload', myFunction);
    }
```